# Does scala foreach block?

Tags: scala, foreach

I can't seem to find any definitive documentation on how `foreach` should behave in Scala when futures are involved.

For example, in the following snippet:

```
def someMethod: Future[Int] = {
  val mySeq: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future(Seq(1,2,3,4))
  mySeq.foreach(x => println(x))
  Future(1)
}
```

Will the Future(1) evaluate only after the foreach completes?

Comment: If you need Futures to happen in a defined order, you have to connect them with `flatMap` or something similar. Otherwise, it depends on the interaction between the ExecutionServices involved how they want to schedule them (and you should treat it as undefined).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Future.foreach` means "call the following code after the `Future` completes succesfully". So the `println` will only be called once `mySeq` has completed. This might happen before the `Future(1)` is called, but equally it might not.

Note that `Future(Seq(1,2,3,4))` executes asynchronously even though the result is a constant. If you replace this with `Future.successful(Seq(1,2,3,4))` then this will complete immediately <strike>and the `println` will happen before the `Future(1)`</strike>. However the subsequent `foreach` call is still asynchronous and may complete after the `Future(1)`

(Thanks to Thilo for the correction)

Comment: Even with `Future.successful`, the `foreach` will still be dispatched to the implicit ExecutionContext and not just run on the current thread, I think. So the `println` can still happen after the `Future(1)`. No?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at exact method implementation, it looks something like this (in Scala 2.11, but don't think it completely changed over version):

```
def foreach[U](f: T => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit = onComplete { _ foreach f }
```

As you may see it is non blocking and will be invoked after `Future` complete.
Essentially it is just syntactic sugar for `onComplete`.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of [`Future.foreach`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#foreach[U](f:T=%3EU)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit) states

> **Asynchronously** processes the value in the future once the value becomes available.

`Future` does not have any blocking methods, except for `result` and `ready` which should [not](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#result(atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)(implicitpermit:scala.concurrent.CanAwait):T) be used directly.